# Magento 2.3 problems on local server

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to install a Magento 2.3 instance to my localhost(WAMP server) but after installation process(I use a command line to install) not Admin part or storefront part works correctly. It shows a lot of errors in a browser console and doesn't load  Admin part at all and front part only partly. I'm using PHP 7.2.4 but also tried to use 7.1.16(it provides the same result).
[image]

And a log file says:

```
[2018-11-30 09:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:10] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/wysiwyg/active_editor.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'theme.active.editor' [] [] 
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Translation' block's name: 'translate' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.components' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/calendar.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'head.calendar' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Ui' block's name: 'logger' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []
[2018-11-30 09:31:11] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp/www/magento/theme_23_final/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/copyright.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'copyright' [] []
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, This is the problem with windows. Windows uses "\" as separator, the array "directories" contains entries with "/" as separator, so the check will always fail.

So you need to fix this by replacing the separator in core file:

```
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator
```

function isPathInDirectories   replace below code in isPathInDirectories function

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Comment: This resolved the problem, thanks. I think this must be fixed in the core as fast as possible

Comment: This shouldn't be used. This is duplicating `str_replace` call that is written in `isValid` method in the same class.

Comment: This is a quick fix and may be Magento will provide a patch to fix this issue.

Comment: Yes but there is a *better* [quick fix here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251999/70494).

Comment: @SaurabhDwivedi  Which file need to edit? Which file consists $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));  ?

Comment: @zus You need to go Magento root directory then under vendor/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Template/File/   Validator.php file.

Comment: @SaurabhDwivedi Still getting same error...

Comment: @SaurabhDwivedi can you pls help my post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/255305/57334

Comment: Thank you so much brother. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue, yesterday on same version : run this query in your db.

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

Then run following command :

```
 bin/magento cache:clean
```

In case if its not work you can see more solutions over [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/109642/21339)

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't help me. I'm not sure that this cases are the same

Comment: I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to install a fresh `Magento 2.3.5-p1` on `Windows 7 32bit 2GB of RAM` (and it's very out of date) using `WAMPServer (php 7.1.16)` and i run into unexpected MANY errors all of kind (if i could say) required js not loaded, poor performance .. all of them are specific and related to `WINDOWS` since Windows and MacOS are **NOT OFFICIALLY** supported as per [this doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).. one of those errors is the one you described her and i confirm the @Saurabh Dwivedi's solution.

To work with Magento on Window with less pain and stress, it's recommanded to to use VM ([link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141407/magento2-running-so-slow-on-localhost-development)) or WSL with Windows 10 ([link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263123/magento-2-running-magento-2-on-windows-using-windows-subsystem-for-linux))

Answer (score -1):

This issue is from windows machine. Remove antivirus and allow firewall rules. Then add file/folders permissions.
Win command:
takeown /F E:/xampp/htdocs/mage23 /R

Now install magento V2.3.0