# Magento 2 wamp admin page doesn't load/display

Tags: admin

I'm trying out Magento 2 using localhost with wamp and I can't get the admin page to load/display?
I do get a page with index.php but it doesn't display the luma logo as in examples I've seen, so unsure if this is correct?
Below - first image is the admin page which is just a dark grey blank page - second image is the index page[image: admin page display]

[image: index page display]

Comment: Check your log files

Comment: I'm not  familiar with magento, I'm just playing about could you provide more details. Thanks Vignesh.

Comment: check system requirements for magento and yours configuration as well

Comment: I know PHP version is 7.2.10

Comment: check log files in following path var/log

Comment: I'm also getting this issue

Comment: [2018-12-03 17:35:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp64/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/header.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'logo' [] []
[2018-12-03 17:35:48] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'C:/wamp64/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'admin.login' [] []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is broken because the recent [github commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8110949e4dd4faa8d36b25ecfeb7779ebbac5741#diff-643a52d0419707fc6b1a9c95a9b5a632):

Fix [Saurabh Dwivedi](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251946/magento-2-3-problems-on-local-server):

IN `www-rootdir\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php`

Replace in the `protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)`:

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

[image: code]

Comment: mark as correct pls, glad it helped