# How to solve Magento 2.3 Sample Data Installation RuntimeException Error in Windows 7?

Tags: installation, magento2.3, windows, proxy, runtime

I try to install magento 2.3 in windows 7, i am getting error like,

```
<span class="text-info">Starting Magento installation:</span><br><span class="text-info">File permissions check...</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 1 / 849]</span><br><span class="text-info">Required extensions check...</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 2 / 849]</span><br><span class="text-info">Enabling Maintenance Mode...</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 3 / 849]</span><br><span class="text-info">Installing deployment configuration...</span><br><span class="hidden">[Progress: 4 / 849]</span><br><span class="text-info">Installing database schema:</span><br><span class="text-danger">[ERROR] RuntimeException: The path "C:/wamp/www/abc/generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data/Proxy.php.2984" cannot be renamed into "C:/wamp/www/abc/generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data/Proxy.php" Warning!rename(C:/wamp/www/abc/generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data/Proxy.php.2984,C:/wamp/www/abc/generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data/Proxy.php): The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (code: 32)
Class Magento\Directory\Helper\Data\Proxy generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only. in C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator.php:135
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Directo...')
#1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Directo...')
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Directo...')
#3 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime.php(38): class_exists('Magento\\Directo...')
#4 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(166): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime->has('Magento\\Directo...')
#5 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(160): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->_inheritInterception('Magento\\Directo...')
#6 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(189): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->_inheritInterception('DirectoryHelper...')
#7 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(140): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->hasPlugins('DirectoryHelper...')
#8 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Config\Config.php(116): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->initialize(Array)
#9 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(116): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Config\Scope), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime), Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime), 'interception', NULL)
#10 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#11 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#12 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#13 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php(188): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager(Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectManager\Config\Developer), Array)
#14 C:\wamp\www\abc\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\ObjectManagerProvider.php(62): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array)
#15 C:\wamp\www\abc\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(820): Magento\Setup\Model\ObjectManagerProvider->get()
#16 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema(Array)
#17 C:\wamp\www\abc\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(367): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 C:\wamp\www\abc\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#19 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#20 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#21 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#22 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#24 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#25 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#26 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#27 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#28 C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#29 C:\wamp\www\abc\setup\index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#30 {main}<span><br>
```

Screenshot :
 [image]

How to solve this error?

Comment: Hey, Can you go to the var/ folder inside the Magento_Root and delete .maintenance.flag file and try again. And by the way what is the PHP version you are using ?

Comment: got any solution ?

Comment: Because if you remove the var/* and generated/* it will fix he issue and the re run the setup:di:compile

Comment: Try above solution and let me know if you still facing the issue.

Comment: paste output of `php -v`.

Comment: @AdityaShah Before install remove var and generated folder Still getting same error.

Comment: Okay then I'll check and update you.

Comment: Solved *** After give write permission successfully installed.

Comment: @AdityaShah  I am getting Unknown hashing algorithm: sha256 error, Complete Error : Warning: hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: sha256 in C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 189  How to solve this error? My php ver 7.2

Comment: yepp generation needs permission :)

Comment: C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 189  Facing it now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87523/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-zus).

Answer (score 2):

Give write permission to the generated folder.

If in windows right click the generated folder and remove the read-only flag.

or if in linux.

Go the magento root folder and run this command.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 generated/
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Set up one owner for default or developer mode**

> In default or developer mode, the following directories must be
>   writable by the user:

- vendor
- app/etc
- pub/static
- var
- Any other static resources
- generated/code
- generated/metadata
- var/view_preprocessed

**Set up one owner for production mode**

> When you’re ready to deploy your site to production, you should remove
>   write access from files in the following directories for improved
>   security:

- vendor
- app/etc
- pub/static
- var
- Any other static resources
- generated/code
- generated/metadata
- var/view_preprocessed

**Make code files and directories read-only**

- Enter the following command to change to production mode

---

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

- Enter the following command

---

```
find app/code var vendor pub/static app/etc generated/code generated/metadata var/view_preprocessed \( -type f -or -type d \) -exec chmod u-w {} + && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

- Enter the following command as a user with root privileges

---

```
find app/code lib pub/static app/etc generated/code generated/metadata var/view_preprocessed \( -type d -or -type f \) -exec chmod g-w {} + && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php
```

**Make code files and directories writable**

```
find app/code lib var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc \( -type d -or -type f \) -exec chmod g+w {} + && chmod o+rwx app/etc/env.php
```

**[Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html)**

Comment: How do to above things in Windows?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/868399/how-to-make-a-folder-read-only-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seems clear the issue is permissions related.

Now, on windows, you may have some hurdles that could be simply resolved on linux.

I found the article https://mage2.pro/t/topic/4734/8 being close to your issue.

I would attempt to find the way to:

1. find the user for your webserver running
2. ensure the user you found is owner of the folder generated and apply this change recursively
3. restart your webserver