# magento 2 admin not working correctly

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module

[image]

I used wamp to install Magento 2 but admin not working correctly, how can I fix it

when I opened "inspect" I found this error
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Magento 2 2.0.0-RC Admin page not found after installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89125/how-to-fix-magento-2-2-0-0-rc-admin-page-not-found-after-installation)

Answer (score 0):

windows is not supported for magento 2.3.

There's quite a few issues that make it stop working, that admin blank screen being one of them.

My advice is to install a virtual box ubuntu server vm, and run magento from there.

This is broken because the recent [github commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/8110949e4dd4faa8d36b25ecfeb7779ebbac5741#diff-643a52d0419707fc6b1a9c95a9b5a632):

Fix [Saurabh Dwivedi](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251946/magento-2-3-problems-on-local-server):

IN `www-rootdir\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php`

Replace in the `protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)`:

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

[image: code]