# Magento 2 : Running magento 2 on windows using windows subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: magento2, installation, setup, windows, local

Is there some good guide on how to use Linux subsystem provided with Windows 10 to set up and run Magento 2?

Comment: What do you mean with "subsystem"? A virtual machine?

Comment: I mean this - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq

Comment: Basically after you have one of the Linux distributions installed in WSL 2 all the rest is same as if running Magento directly on Linux. You can access the files trough \\wsl$\..\ path path from Windows host. I am developing Magento 2 like this, the only issue I have is slow sync of file changes in WSL in PhpStom.

Comment: Yes. But if you want to access an existing project you can use symlinking to /var/www/html as I've mentioned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Introduction:**

The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is a new Windows 10 feature that enables you to run native Linux command-line tools directly on Windows, alongside your traditional Windows desktop and modern store apps.

The Windows Subsystem for Linux lets developers run GNU/Linux environment -- including most command-line tools, utilities, and applications -- directly on Windows, unmodified, without the overhead of a virtual machine.

You can:

- Choose your favorite GNU/Linux distributions from the Windows Store.
- Run common command-line free software such as grep, sed, awk, or
  other ELF-64 binaries. Run Bash shell scripts and GNU/Linux
  command-line applications including:
- **Tools:** vim, emacs, tmux
- **Languages:** PHP, Javascript/node.js, Ruby, Python, C/C++, C# & F#, Rust, Go, etc.
- **Services:** sshd, MySQL, Apache, lighttpd Install additional software using own GNU/Linux distribution package manager.
- Invoke  Windows
  applications using a Unix-like command-line shell.
- Invoke GNU/Linux applications on Windows.

**Installation:**

- Enable developer mode from settings.

### [image]

- Open powershell/cmd as admin and enable WSL using following command

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName
> Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

You can also enable it from window features in GUI.

- Restart your system.
- Install distro of your choice from the windows store. (Just search for eg. Ubuntu and install).
- Access WSL using `bash` command on cmd.
- It will ask you to set username and password for your linux user.
- Check your distro using the following command ;

> lsb_release -a

- Install apache using the following command;

> sudo apt-get install apache2

- Start apache using the following command;

> sudo service apache2 start

- Access localhost to see if apache has been started successfully. Just open up the browser of your choice and type 'localhost'.
- Install mysql using following command ;

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server

- Start mysql using the following command ;

> sudo service mysql start

- Access mysql to make sure it is running properly

> mysql -uroot -p

Use exit/quit command to exit mysql.

- Install PHP using the following command

> sudo apt-get install php7.2

You can install php version of your choice by just mentioning the version.

- Check if PHP has been installed using the following command;

> php -v

- Check if you have all the modules needed by placing `index.php` having  `phpinfo()` at `/var/www/html` and accessing `localhost/index.php`
- Install composer using following command;

> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php

If you do not have curl, install it using `sudo apt-get install curl`

- Make symlink of your Windows Magento project folder/ from where you want to access Magento files in /var/www/html using ;

> sudo ln -s /mnt/c/projects/magento23 /var/www/html/magento23

Note that all the windows filesystem can be found mounted in /mnt folder.

- cd into your symlinked folder and install Magento using composer.

In my opinion, the WSL way of using Magento in windows is much faster than native windows and much more hassle-free than installing a virtual machine and dealing with its problems. You also have direct access to all project files so you can use your preferred editor for coding.

**Note :** Currently I have to start apache and mysql server after every restart but I will update if I can get it added to systemctl boot time.

Comment: I've my code inside Windows system and I created symlink as you guided. But It is not generating static content and showing static content

Comment: you have created symlink for whole Magento folder in  /var/www/html/ right? It should be working if you've done that.

Comment: I want to setup magento 2 pwa studio. Can share guide how to do that? I tried magento 2 official guide but it is not working.

Comment: I have not tried to setup PWA studio in subsystem but I was able to set it up fine on my Linux machine using the same instructions..

Comment: I will try it when I have some time and update you.

Comment: That would be great help Vivek. thank you so much. Also, create a video tutorial when you are working if possible. Thank you

Comment: Can you please check this error? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/271144/pwa-studio-yarn-build-error

Comment: Magento not loading static files might be a separate issue that doesn't have to do with loading it under WSL, I had the same under Linux Mint. See also https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder

Comment: I have set up WSL ubuntu with Magento 2.3 but magneto is very slow. cache is enabled and Magento is in default mode. My system is core i5 with 8 GB RAM and SSD.

Comment: You can look into https://medium.com/@leandrocrs/speeding-up-wsl-i-o-up-than-5x-fast-saving-a-lot-of-battery-life-cpu-usage-c3537dd03c74